# Including CSRF token in the layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to include the CSRF token in the layout to make it globally accessible for my javascript code:

```
. . .
<body data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
. . .
```

Is this approach a good pratice, or will it introduce any security holes / other problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that Laravel has a built-in way of managing, actually.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

Answer (score 1):

In the head section of your layout.blade.php add the following meta tag:

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    ...
</head>
```

And the in document.ready add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    ...
});
```